# Flink, what does method setDbStoragePath do in RocksDBStateBackend?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm using flink 1.11 with RocksDBStateBackend, the code looks like this:

```java
RocksDBStateBackend stateBackend = new RocksDBStateBackend("hdfs:///flink-checkpoints", true);
stateBackend.setDbStoragePath(config.getString("/tmp/rocksdb/"));
env.setStateBackend(stateBackend);
```

My questions are:

1. My understanding is that when `DbStoragePath` is set, Flink will put all checkpoints and state in a local disk (in my case `/tmp/rocksdb`) before storing into hadoop `hdfs:///flink-checkpoints`. Is that right? And if it's right, should I always set `DbStoragePath` for better performance?
2. Because Flink doesn't delete old checkpoints, I have a job periodically clean up old checkpoints. But I'm not sure is it safe to do that if I set incremental checkpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DbStoragePath` is the location on the local disk where RocksDB keeps its working state. By default the tmp directory will be used. Ideally this should be fastest available disk -- e.g., SSD. Normally this is configured via `state.backend.rocksdb.localdir`.

If you are using incremental checkpoints, then the SST files from the `DbStoragePath` are copied to the `state.checkpoints.dir`. Otherwise full snapshots are written to the checkpoint directory and the `DbStoragePath` isn't involved.

Flink automatically deletes old checkpoints, except after canceling a job that is using retained checkpoints. It's not obvious how to safely delete an incremental, retained checkpoint -- you need to somehow know if any of those SST files are still referred to from the latest checkpoint. You might ask for advice on the user mailing list.

Comment: Thank you! If I don't set `RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION`, I don't need to manually clean up old checkpoints, right?